# .filter not working on array with objects in javascsript

Tags: javascript

I want to filter items array such that theItem with productid "b" is removed from the items array, so that only items with prdocutid a and c remain, but the filter is not working !

```
const items = [{productid:'a'}, {productid:'b'}, {productid:'c'}];

const theItem = {productid:'b'};

items.filter( item => item.productid === theItem.productid);

items.forEach(element => console.log(element));
```

Comment: `item.filter` returns new array filtered, not filtered itself.
So you should use like `items = items.filter...`

Comment: It's frustrating that there isn't any way in Javascript to tell destructive operations like `sort` from non-destructive ones like `filter`. Unfortunately you just have to memorize. *Most* of the array methods are non-destructive.

Comment: `filtereditems = items.filter((item) => item.productid !== 'b');`

Answer (score 2):

`filter()` does not modify the variable itself. Instead, it returns a new list/array of the result. Here is the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

Here is the solution to your question:

```
const items = [{ productid:'a' }, { productid:'b' }, { productid:'c' }];

const theItem = { productid:'b' };

// assigning the value to a variable
const results = items.filter(item => item.productid === theItem.productid);

results.forEach(element => console.log(element));
```

```
Output: {productid: "b"}
```

Answer (score 1):

Array.prototype.filter() returns a new filtered array, it does not **mutate** the original array. You need to modify your code like this:

**Method - 1:**
**Change the original array items to let instead of const so you can save the result from filter into items then iterate over items:**
//Changed from const to let so I can save the filtered array into this array

```
let items = [{productid:'a'}, {productid:'b'}, {productid:'c'}];
const theItem = {productid:'b'};

//Store the resultant array from filter into the original array 
items = items.filter( item => item.productid === theItem.productid);

items.forEach(element => console.log(element));
```

**Method - 2:**
**Store the filtered array in a new Array:**

```
const items = [{productid:'a'}, {productid:'b'}, {productid:'c'}];
const theItem = {productid:'b'};

//Store the resultant array from filter into a new array 
const filteredItems = items.filter( item => item.productid === theItem.productid);

filteredItems.forEach(element => console.log(element));
```